# tkinter OptionMenu subclass command and option issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a few OptionMenus with the same configuration and I found this example:

```
class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
        self.var = tk.StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
        self.config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white',width=12)
        self['menu'].config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white')
```

From my main code I call it like this:

```
comboBox_value = ['a','b','c']
oM = MyOptionMenu(root,'Select',comboBox_value)
oM.grid(row=5,column=1)
```

Everything runs, but in the GUI OptionMenu I get one option a,b,c instead of 3 options a then b then c.
Also  if I try to run it like this:

```
oM = MyOptionMenu(root,'Select',comboBox_value, command = func1)
oM.grid(row=5,column=1)
```

I get this error:

```
om = MyOptionMenu(frame_camera,'Select',comboBox_value, command=update_QE)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'command'
```

It doesn't know what command is ...
Any thoughts on how to remedy these issues?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs regarding the error message

Comment: Thanks, I used *comboBox_value instead of comboBox_value and it displays the a,b,c options correctly now. Still need to figure out why command isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass *keyword arguments* as well:

```py
class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):

    def __init__(self, master, status, *options, **kwargs): # added **kwargs
        self.var = tk.StringVar(master)
        self.var.set(status)
        OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options, **kwargs) # passed **kwargs
        self.config(font=('calibri',10), bg='white', width=12)
        self['menu'].config(font=('calibri',10), bg='white')

...
oM = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select', *comboBox_value, command=func1)
...
```

From your posted code, I guess that you have both `from tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk`.  Wildcard import is not recommended and so just use the second one.